# Dismissing to rootViewController without calling each viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

My View Contollers are like MainView -> NavigationController A -> ViewController A -> ViewController B -> ViewController C, I want to dismiss ViewControllers (A,B and C) and present MainView again... I used this line

```
 self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

and it works just fine.. the problem is while dismissing viewControllers (A,B and C) it calls every viewDidAppear and this runs code that I don't want to be run.. what's the best practice to dismiss and go back to MainView without calling each viewController

Comment: @Sammy
 1- I don't use storyboards
2- I present each view as full screen view
this is my code for going to ViewController A

 let vc = ViewControllerA()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        senderVC.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it is done via Storyboard. I don't know how to do it via code. I hope it helps
In your MainViewController add this:

```
@IBAction func unwindToMainView(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) { }
```

In all otherViewController (viewController A,ViewController B,ViewController C),
Click and drag like this
[image]

Then chose the segue you added in the mainVC

[image]

Now select that segue and give it an identifier
[image]

From here you can perform segue with that identifier wherever you want. I use button to perform that segue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must have some other code that is causing the issue.

Here is a complete example...

- `PresDisViewController` is the starting view controller
- its button creates a nav controller with `ViewControllerA` as its root
- `ViewControllerA` has a button that pushes `ViewControllerB`
- `ViewControllerB` has a button that pushes `ViewControllerC`
- `ViewControllerC` has a button that executes your `self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)`

Each VC implements `viewDidAppear()` and prints itself to the debug console.

Output when I run it:

```
viewDidAppear scratchy.PresDisViewController
viewDidAppear scratchy.ViewControllerA
viewDidAppear scratchy.ViewControllerB
viewDidAppear scratchy.ViewControllerC
viewDidAppear scratchy.PresDisViewController
```

As you see, `viewDidAppear` is NOT called in the VCs when the nav controller is dismissed.

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {

    let btn: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.setTitle("Do Push", for: .normal)
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(btn)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            btn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])

        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func didTap(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        let vc = ViewControllerB()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("viewDidAppear", NSStringFromClass(self.classForCoder))
    }

}

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

    let btn: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.setTitle("Do Push", for: .normal)
        v.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(btn)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            btn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])

        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func didTap(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        let vc = ViewControllerC()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("viewDidAppear", NSStringFromClass(self.classForCoder))
    }

}

class ViewControllerC: UIViewController {

    let btn: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.setTitle("Do Dismiss", for: .normal)
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(btn)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            btn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])

        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func didTap(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("viewDidAppear", NSStringFromClass(self.classForCoder))
    }

}


class PresDisViewController: UIViewController {

    let btn: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.setTitle("Do Present", for: .normal)
        v.backgroundColor = .orange
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(btn)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])

        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func didTap(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        let vcA = ViewControllerA()
        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vcA)
        navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("viewDidAppear", NSStringFromClass(self.classForCoder))
    }

}
```